# Change the font size in the book class

Tags: fontsize, templates, document-configuration

I'm using thesis template of my University with pre-defined page properties. I need just to change the font size from 11 to 12.

You can edit it directly through the sharelatex.com

[Link to my project: open please Chapter 3: Proposed algorithm.](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5a0740c1ef84202348e3b13e)

Many thanks for any advice.

[image]

P.S.:

0) It's a new project with new properties, the old my question I removed.

1) I've tried *geometry* package, but still changing font changing margins as well

2) I can't remove "twoside" from the documentclass, due to the fact that in the future I will print that thesis.

P.P.S. with David's code it looks better, but margins are still not the same.
[image]

Comment: Is there something stopping you from changing `11pt` to `12pt` in the list of options passed to the `book` document class? What seems really weird about the template is that it doesn't set the page size and text block size parameters directly. Do you happen to know the values of these parameters? If so, you could use the `geometry` package to fix the parameter values once and for all, i.e., make them independent of whether `11pt` or `12pt` is the main font size.

Comment: What you are providing here is a link to your project, and it does not compile. I said yesterday, just post a link, and later told you to bin that template, as it is just bad. What you did not make clear so far: The margin change is sudden within just one chapter,, which is a more than clear indicator, that your code is messed up. And you are told by the compiler that it is indeed the case.

Comment: The change is not sudden, is it in all chapters. Why are you referring to chapter three? The book class sets different margins for different font sizes, which also means differing text widths. Your template defines a *FIXED* textwidth, which means the text block gets moved around leading to very ugly results. So basically, add `\setlength\textwidth{35em}` *after* you load `macroses.sty`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you for helping, I understand you. That  template is not good so far, but it's the oficial one and it is more convinient for me to use pre-defined template becase I'm a beginner at Latex. Thanks for the patience and indulgence :). 
Chapter 3 because I started to write from this chapter and its more convinient to test on a completed page. 

After you suggestion it finally looks good.

Comment: It might be official, but it throws errors. Something you as a beginner do not need. You shouldn't even in the slightest have the problem you describe, it purely comes from that strange  `macroses.sty`. Please have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

Answer (score 2):

There are just four relevant lengths for the horizontal setting.

At 11pt

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}


\typeout{tw: \the\textwidth}
\typeout{os: \the\oddsidemargin}
\typeout{es: \the\evensidemargin}
\typeout{mw: \the\marginparwidth}

\begin{document}

zzz

\end{document}
```

produces

```
tw: 360.0pt
os: 22.0pt
es: 70.0pt
mw: 106.0pt
```

If you change  to 12pt you get

```
tw: 390.0pt
os: 10.0pt
es: 52.0pt
mw: 88.0pt
```

but you want the 11pt widths so set them back:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\setlength{\textwidth}{360pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{22pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{70pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{106pt}

\typeout{tw: \the\textwidth}
\typeout{os: \the\oddsidemargin}
\typeout{es: \the\evensidemargin}
\typeout{mw: \the\marginparwidth}

\begin{document}

zzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shall I quote l2tabu concerning recommendations about lengths like `\oddsidemargin`?

Comment: @TeXnician you could but I think the general advice in l2tabu does not apply here.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle! It looks 1000 times better, but margins are still not the same. I put an aditional image to the topic to show you.

Comment: @NikolayVolkov the margins are identical in the code above. If they are different for you something must be resetting them. Did you use the numbers that I used or follow the process of using `\typeout` to see what numbers you have at 11pt and re-setting then at 12pt? (You should use the typeout)

Comment: of course you need the `\typeout` and the resetting to be at the very end of the preamble after all your other code that has set these lengths. @NikolayVolkov